Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2n}{e}(\arcsin(\frac{k}{n})-\arcsin(\frac{k-1}{n}))$
I'm trying to evaluate $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ where
$$f(n)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2n}{e}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)$$
We have:
$f(1)\approx1.15573$
$f(10^2)\approx1.22410$
$f(10^4)\approx1.22533$
$f(10^6)\approx1.22535$

My attempt
I've only been able to find the following equivalent expressions for $L$.
$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{2n}{e}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$
$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{2n}{e}\arcsin\left(\frac{k\sqrt{n^2-(k-1)^2}-(k-1)\sqrt{n^2-k^2}}{n^2}\right)\right)\right)$$
$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{2n}{e}\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{(n^2-k^2)(n^2-(k-1)^2)}+k(k-1)}{n^2}\right)\right)\right)$$

Context
The limit comes from the following geometrical construction that I made up.
In a semicircle with diameter $na$ where $a=\frac{2}{e}$, draw chords of lengths $a,2a,3a,\dots,na$ that meet at one of the endpoints of the semicircle. Here is an example with $n=6$.

Consider the arcs between neighboring chord endpoints. The product of the $n$ arc lengths is $f(n)$ from above.

Why I think $L$ might have a closed form
I think $L$ might have a closed form, because a similar geometrical construction seems to yield a limit with a closed form.
Instead of starting with a semicircle (which is a cicular segment with central angle $\pi$), let's start with a circular segment with central angle $\pi/3$, with a bounding chord of length $nb$ where $b=\frac{3\sqrt3}{2e}$. Draw chords of lengths $b,2b,3b,\dots,nb$ that meet at one of the end points of the arc. Here is an example with $n=6$.

Consider the arcs between neighboring chord endpoints. The product of the $n$ arc lengths is $g(n)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{3\sqrt3n}{e}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{k-1}{2n}\right)\right)$.
Numerical investigation suggests that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)=1$.

Just to confirm: here $e = 2.718\ldots$, not some arbitrary number?

@MichaelLugo Correct, $e=2.718\dots$.

Can you show how you found out the arccos part? It will be very helful

@Gwen I used the fact that $A-B=\arccos(\cos(A-B))$ if $0<A-B<\pi$.

Oh alright got it @Dan

Anyway, it should be possible to rewrite $L$ as the exponential of the integral of a logarithm.

$$
L = \sqrt[4]{{\frac{{{\rm e}^\gamma  }}{{2\pi }}}}\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\binom{2n}{n}\frac{{\zeta (n)}}{{2^{2n}  \cdot 2n}}} } \right) = \sqrt[4]{{\frac{{8{\rm e}^{\gamma  - 1} }}{\pi }}}\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\binom{2n}{n}\frac{{\zeta (n) - 1}}{{2^{2n}  \cdot 2n}}} } \right) \= 1.2253517701107728567819327 \ldots
$$

Long comment. What I proved in this posting about an  asymptotic formula for a related product actually works for $\alpha, \beta > -1$ (see the statement of the corollary in the link). The upshot of this asymptotic formula in OP's case is that
\begin{align*}
&\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2n}{e} \left[ \arcsin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - \arcsin\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) \right] \\
&\sim \frac{1}{(2\pi n)^{1/4}} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1-k^{-1}}} \\
&\sim \sqrt[4]{\frac{e^{\gamma}}{2\pi}} \exp\Biggl[ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log\Biggl( \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1-k^{-1}}} \Biggr) -\frac{1}{4k} \Biggr] \\
&\approx 1.2253517701\ldots
\end{align*}
I am skeptical that this expression has an elementary closed form.

Thanks. In my question, in the section called "Why I think $L$ might have a closed form",  I show that there is numerical evidence for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)$ having a closed form. What makes $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)$ different, in terms of having a closed form?

@Dan, The limiting constant essentially arises from the product of the form $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}t^{\alpha},\mathrm{d}t,\tag{}$$ where $\alpha$ comes from the asymptotic behavior of your integrand, $(\arcsin x)'=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ or $(\arcsin(x/2))'=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$, near the boundary of $[0, 1]$. Now this $\alpha$ is different in the two cases, one admitting telescoping of terms in $\text{()}$ to yield a closed form, while the other case not. (I know this comment lacks lots of details, and it would be helpful to give a look on the link in my answer.)
